# Getting external data into web application

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications

I am an experienced application developer who now has to develop a web application which I don't have a lot of experience in.

I am working on a project that has a number of distributed server components. It currently has a client application that monitors these components, view alarms and logs etc. The state of each of the server machines is delivered via a proprietary protocol over tcp/ip.

The current UI based app has a thread that continually monitors the socket connection for messages and once received stores in-memory the current state of everything and then displays this to the user.

My question is how do I achieve something similar in a web application environment. My first thought was to create a similar comms thread on server start and then when the user requests data the response is built up from the in-memory data but reading about web applications starting your own threads is bad practise.

I have read a little about using Quartz or TimerTask to run periodic schedule tasks in web applications but this task is more continuous. Is it still the way to go?

I'm developing the web app in Java using JSF running Tomcat on Linux. Oh and the application will have a low number of concurrent users. (25 max but more likely 2 or 3)

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1

Using [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) is good. It is advised not to use TimerTask.

Approach 2

I am assuming that the web application has some sort of database. Since you need to display the states on user request, not real time what you can do is that write a standalone daemon application (not a web application) which reads for server states and updates a table which is visible to the web application. When the user request is made this table can be referred to produce output.

Comment: A more better approach would be to use Message Driven Beans (MDB). The web application can post message to MDB which then does all they need to do ;). A little combination of AJAX which connects to a backend JSF component which query some sort of signal (in DB or in cache) set by MDB would achieve similar behavior.

Comment: Indeed Messaging is one better approach, but since he is using Tomcat Web Server not a J2EE Application Server this is not possible.

Comment: TomEE+ may be an option :). Otherwise, I would just use JBoss AS 7 which is quite lightweight as well.

Comment: Good options, but still have to move away from/make changes to the existing Tomcat Server. Up to @ChillyMc to decide.

Comment: I am not tied down to using Tomcat and am open to other suggestions. I would be more worried about the learning curve on the J2EE environment in addition to already learning the web application one!

Answer (score 0):

Why make this a server concern? In your client (the browser) you can poll the current state and adjust the display according. Doing this removes a lot of complexity.

As to how your client will be updating, that's dependent on your app. If you can allow for only modern browsers, you could look into HTML5 WebSockets. Other options are using AJAX for partial update of the screen or a complete screen refresh.